# Process builder is not triggering

Tags: workflow, approval-process, visual-workflow, flow, process-builder

I have created a wf rule with time based action which will run after 1 hr rule triggered date and update checkbox send_Email__c to true.

In process builder i have added the criteria is 
if Owner_active__c(formula field on custom object)=true && 
sen_Email__C =true then in immidiate action sending an email alert.

```
  made checkbox Recursion=true
```

here the problem is after wf is updating a field to true ,process builder is not calling and sending mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Sorry if this sounds to simplistic but did you activate the correct version in your process of the process builder? If not, we've all been there.

2) If it is activated, why not break this issue down?
a) Have the process builder check two fields that do not depend on a formula or WF to update it (i.e. two text fields) and see if the email works.
b) If it doesn't, then check why emails do not work?
c) If it does work, then try adding checking the formula field with one text field. If it works then add the WF updated field.

See what happens step by step and then update this question with what you find.

Comment: just checked  re-evaluate checkbox for field update and it is working correctly now.

Comment: your comment about this checkbox saved me some hours! Thx bro.